# Yocto Custom Applications Tree

Tags: yocto

I want to compile my applications with the following tree in yocto project:

```
 myapps/
├── Papps1
│   ├── module-apps1
│   │   └── app1
│   │       ├── include
│   │       │   ├── include files
│   │       ├── configure.ac
│   │       ├── Makefile
│   │       └── other source files
│   └── Papps2
│       └── app2
│          ├── include
│          ├── include files
│          ├── CMakeLists.txt
│          └── other source files
└── recipies_apps
    ├── recipies_app1.bb
    └── recipies_app2.bb
```

is there any solution to compile this architecture tree in yocto ?